# Unable to copy 3 input fields in JS

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Wants to merge 3 input field's value in 1 input

Wants to print 'fname mnane lname in'  fullname input field.

after than copy fullname value into fullname2.

My code is below.

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label>Last Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="lname" type="text" onchange="setaddress()" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label>Middle Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="mname" type="text" onchange="setaddress()" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="fname" type="text" onchange="setaddress()" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<label>Complete Name</label>
<input class="form-control" id="fullname" type="text" readonly>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<label>Complete Name Again</label>
<input class="form-control" id="fullname2" type="text" readonly>
</div>
```

JS

```
function setaddress() {
  var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
  var mname = document.getElementById('mname').value;
  var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;

  document.getElementById('fullname').value =  fname +" " + mname +" " +  lname;
}

    //using JS 2 to copy input field

        window.onload = function() {
    var src = document.getElementById("fullname"),
        dst = document.getElementById("fullname2");
    src.addEventListener('input', function() {
        dst.value = src.value;
    });
};
```

Comment: What's not working? You get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

innerHTML is for normal tags if you want to change value of input field you should use

```
document.getElementById('fullname').value =  fname +" " + mname +" " +  lname;
document.getElementById('fullname2').value =  fname +" " + mname +" " +  lname;
```

Comment: but value in not copying into fullname2

Comment: In setaddress() you should repeat the given statement again by fullname2 id